# Android WebView Kotlin - Not able to copy

Tags: javascript, kotlin, webview

Here is my code from Kotlin:

```
package com.bn.leafylives

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.bn.leafylives.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Declare webView as a class-level property
    private lateinit var webView: WebView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize webView
        webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        // loading http://www.google.com url in the WebView.
        webView.loadUrl("SITE")
        webView.setOnLongClickListener {
            // Execute JavaScript to copy to the clipboard
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:copyTextToClipboard()")
            true
        }

        // this will enable JavaScript.
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        // WebViewClient allows you to handle
        // onPageFinished and override URL loading.
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    }
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack()
            return true
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no webpage history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

My site has got a share button which works like this:

```
const copy = async () => {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url + "\n\nRead more about home gardens!"
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(url).then(function() {
        console.log('Copied!');
    }, function() {
        console.log('Copy error')
    });
    document.getElementById('btn-top').innerHTML="Copied!";
    document.getElementById('btn-down').innerHTML="Copied!";
    await delay(1000);
    document.getElementById('btn-top').innerHTML="Share";
    document.getElementById('btn-down').innerHTML="Share";
}
```

The share button copies text fine when in the website, but is not able to copy in the Android app. I am not an Android dev so I don't understand the issue.

Here is the error log:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "Copy error", source: SITE (47)
```

I tried enabling WRITE_ACCESS but it is not working.